# javascript Promise.all returns last promise only

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a script like:

```
var a = [{'a': 1},{'b': 2}]
var allPromises = new Array(a.length)
for(var i in a) {
    allPromises[i] = Promise.resolve().then(response => {
      console.log(i)
      console.log(a[i])
      // Do somethig on every loop with key and value
      return i
    })
}

Promise.all(allPromises).then(response => console.log(response))
```

Here in my `for loop` it only gives me last index and value of last index while I want the value on every loop and perform some action with key and value.. But I am getting the last key and value only..

I tried getting the value on `Promise.all`'s response but didnt work.

How can I get the index of my array on `allPromises`'s response ?

I can do it by makeing a counter. But when I again call the function the counter is reset so I donnt want to use the counter.

Is there anyway I can get index on every loop for promise ?

Comment: Using `let` instead of `var` would also work with the way the for loop is written because `let` works with block scoping, not only function scoping. But I would also prefer the solution by @jfriend00 because in my opinion the `Array.map` / `Array.forEach` is better readable.

Comment: You already have some good answers, so you don't need another :) But to add one more option to the mix: since you already use resolve, you can pass `i` into it, so it becomes the parameter inside `then` (`resolve`) and use that parameter instead of the outer `i` variable: https://jsfiddle.net/vscbgwpm/

Comment: Using `var` is a typical JS scoping ambush here. You should use `let` instead of `var`. Or @Me.Name's idea is also pretty valid and good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `i` variable in the `.then()` handler inside your `for` loop isn't what you think it is.  Your `for` loop has already run to completion before any of your `.then()` handlers get called (since they always run asynchronously on a future tick).  Thus, you only think you're seeing the last promise, but actually all the promises are working fine, it's just that they are all returning the last value of `i`.

You can fix it by using `.forEach()` to iterate your array because it uniquely captures each value of `i`.

```js
var a = [{'a': 1},{'b': 2}]
var allPromises = new Array(a.length);
a.forEach(function(item, i) {
     allPromises[i] = Promise.resolve().then(response => {
      console.log(i)
      console.log(a[i])
      // Do somethig on every loop with key and value
      return i
    })
});

Promise.all(allPromises).then(response => console.log(response))
```

Or, since you're generating an array as a result, you could use `.map()`:

```js
var a = [{'a': 1},{'b': 2}]
var allPromises = a.map(function(item, i) {
  return Promise.resolve().then(response => {
    console.log(i)
    console.log(a[i])
    // Do somethig on every loop with key and value
    return i
  })
});

Promise.all(allPromises).then(response => console.log(response))
```

Comment: That's exactly the first thing that came to my mind after reading the post.

Comment: You could even replace the `forEach` with a `map` function and transform every entry into a promise for that entry. This would then avoid initializing an empty array beforehand.

Comment: @ajaegle- Yep, I added that as an option.

Comment: Thanks mate, helped me with an angular promise

Answer (score 0):

I think the promise all is cool, but it's a pity to told you that is you are wrong. this is a promise all demo:

```js
var p = [];
p[0] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "one"); 
}); 
p[1] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "two"); 
}); 
p[2] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "three"); 
});
p[3]= new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, "four");
});
p[4] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000, "done");
});

Promise.all(p).then(value => { 
  console.log(value);
});
```

so I think your code is look like this:

```js
var arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];
var p = [];
arr.forEach((val, err) => {
  var promiseFunction = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(val);
  });
  p.push(promiseFunction);
})

Promise.all(p).then(value => { 
  console.log(value);
});
```

what do you think?